# Limiting Text Input Based On Another Text Input

Tags: javascript

It seems pretty simple but I can't find a good way to do it.

I am doing a research bar which allow users to search something in terms of price mini and price maxi.

So :
I have two text input types (in html of course) "price_mini?" and "price_maxi?".
"Price_mini" cannot be bigger than "price_maxi".
How can I limit the users input of "price_mini" so that if does not allow the user to enter more than the "price_maxi" variable's input and then display an error on save(search) if the mini number is bigger than price_maxi.

Comment: Are you saving to the database real time as the user enters input or could you just display an error explaining price_mini has to be lower before being able to save?

Comment: In fact, i am doing a search bar for a website. The user can't be able to submit if price_mini is bigger than price_maxi, so i'd like to display an error before sending

Comment: Ok, you will get better answers if you edit your question to state you want to display an error on save(search) if the mini number is bigger than price_maxi. You can display the error as they type or on submit but either way submitting/saving has to be blocked if the error exists. As of now people were guessing what you wanted to do.

Comment: Thank you for advices, I tried my best for the thread but I am not really good in English. ^^

Comment: No worries - I can make the edit for you then if you want.

Comment: I tried to edit it ! is that better ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work, I couldn't get JSFiddle to handle the form to show you a good example and I don't do much in plain javascript now in days so pardon me if there is a small error or two.

HTML

```
<form name="myForm" onSubmit="submit()" method="post">
    <input name="price_mini" type="text">
    <input name="price_maxi" type="text">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Javascript

```
function submit(){
    var price_mini = document.forms["myForm"]["price_mini"].value;
    var price_maxi = document.forms["myForm"]["price_maxi"].value;

   if(Number(price_mini) > Number(price_maxi)){
    alert("Minimum price must be less than maximum price!");
   }else{
    // Your search code here
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer

Comment: I tried something like what you did but another problem is still here. I explain : I got an alert but my controller.php (the php script which handle the research fonction) is still called (with wrong parameter so) I am lookin for something that block the php script ^^ . I thought javascript handle this by default but it look like he isnt

Comment: If it is in an IF/ELSE statement like above where you replace the //Your search code here with the call to your PHP Script it should never run unless the number is less than the maximum. You could try adding "return;" after the alert inside the if statement as well.

Comment: I was not using the else statement. And i used a return(false) , i also tried history.back and several things like that. So maybe the problem is somewhere else

Comment: I found the problem, I didnt know that i had to use "return" also in the form.
I mean :
onsubmit="return submit()" to check the return value of the fonction !
So it's working now, thank you !

Comment: No worries - glad I could help!

Answer (score -1):

Imagine this html

```
 <input id="min" type="text">
 <input id="max" type="text">
```

This should be the correct javascript

```
 var min = document.getElementById("min");
 var max = document.getElementById("max");
 min.change(function() {
    if(Number(this.value) > Number(max.value)) {
         this.value = max.value; // replace min with the same max value if it's bigger
    }
 }
```

Comment: @Anthony just to point out there are some assumptions made in this script as to what you want to happen if the number is larger.

Comment: However, this is a valid answer. OP can make as he wants inside the `if()` statement

Comment: There wasn't a mention of it being invalid - it was simply expressing caution to Anthony since he may not yet be comfortable with javascript enough to realize what you had put inside the script based on him asking the question.

Comment: Not sure - I didn't vote on anything in this question yet.

Comment: I don't make you guilty, but there are almost one person trolling this topic. This only makes me laugh with the copy&paste&little-edition users hahahahha

Answer (score -1):

Let's assume that this is your HTML.

```
<input id="min" type="text">
<input id="max" type="text">
```

The working JavaScript is this with the behavior if the `max` field is empty.

```
var min = document.querySelector('#min');
var max = document.querySelector('#max');

var calculate = function() {
  if(max.value == '') return;
  if(Number(min.value) > Number(max.value)) {
    min.value = max.value;
  }
}

min.addEventListener('input', calculate);
max.addEventListener('input', calculate);
```

Answer (score -1):

You should compare them when they have value `(min && max)`. If you notice that `min` is higher you can alert to the user or change it automatically to the lowest or to the highest.

```js
$('.calc_input').change( function() {
  var min = $('#min').val();
  var max = $('#max').val();
  if ( (min && max) && min > max ) {
    alert('This can not be!');
    // $('#min').val() = max;
    // $('#max').val() = min;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Min:<input id="min" class="calc_input">
<br>
Max:<input id="max"  class="calc_input">
```